# FileNotFound exception in CPP code

Tags: c++, dialog

Tried passing File path in WCHAR but it gave me WCHAR is incompatible with const WCHAR so tried Hardcoding but still getting exception

```
void Read_Title(WCHAR FilePath) {
//const WCHAR FILE_PATH = FilePath;
IPropertySetStorage *pPropSetStg = NULL;
IPropertyStorage *pPropStg = NULL;
PROPSPEC propspec;
PROPVARIANT propWrite;
PROPVARIANT propRead;
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

hr = StgOpenStorageEx(L"c:\\users\qs4vbn\desktop\siemens_training\project2\project2\main.cpp",
    STGM_DIRECT | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE |
    STGM_READWRITE,
    STGFMT_ANY,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    IID_IPropertySetStorage,
    reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pPropSetStg));

if (FAILED(hr))
    throw L"Failed StgOpenStorageEx";
}
```

Comment: try c:\\users\\qs4vbn\\desktop\\siemens_training\\project2\\project2\\main.cpp or  c:/users/qs4vbn/desktop/siemens_training/project2/project2/main.cpp

Comment: In almost all places where Windows is using `'\'` as a separator, it can just as well use a `'/'`. Saves you some typing, not having to escape the `'\'`s, and (imo) also makes the strings easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your path in this function contains only the first paragraph with double backslash.

```
hr = StgOpenStorageEx(L"c:\\users\qs4vbn\desktop\siemens_training\project2\project2\main.cpp",
    STGM_DIRECT | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE |
    STGM_READWRITE,
    STGFMT_ANY,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    IID_IPropertySetStorage,
    reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pPropSetStg));
```

Have you tried using the path with double backslashes all the way like

```
hr = StgOpenStorageEx(L"c:\\users\\qs4vbn\\desktop\\siemens_training\\project2\\project2\\main.cpp",
    STGM_DIRECT | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE |
    STGM_READWRITE,
    STGFMT_ANY,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    IID_IPropertySetStorage,
    reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pPropSetStg));
```